# After installation of vtk with brew (macosx): "import vtk" aborts python console

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, vtk, failed-installation

I tried to install vtk with homebrew but, now when I `import vtk` on Python, my python session is aborted...

I work on MacOSX and I ran this line:

```
brew install vtk --with-qt --with-python --with-pyqt
```

It returns:

```
....
[ 29%] Built target vtkFiltersCore
    make: *** [all] Error 2

    READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
    If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
      https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues
....
```

After that I read that I should use this line:

```
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=1 VERBOSE=1 brew install vtk --qt --python --pyqt
```

After a long time, it returns:

```
....
 ==> Caveats
    Even without the --with-qt option, you can display native VTK render windows
    from python. Alternatively, you can integrate the RenderWindowInteractor
    in PyQt, PySide, Tk or Wx at runtime. Read more:
        import vtk.qt4; help(vtk.qt4) or import vtk.wx; help(vtk.wx)

    Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
    in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
    this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
    please run:
      mkdir -p /Users/TheUser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
      echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/TheUser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
    ==> Summary
      /usr/local/Cellar/vtk/7.0.0_3: 3,203 files, 107.7M
```

So I ran the mkdir & echo lines

And when I tried `import vtk` in the Python console, it returns:

```
    Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
    Abort trap: 6
```

I retried to reinstall it later:

```
==> Installing vtk from homebrew/science
Error: vtk-7.0.0_3 already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink vtk`
```

So I did the unlink, and I reran `HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS=1 VERBOSE=1 brew install vtk --qt --python --pyqt` .

The result:

```
==> Patching VTK to use system Python 2
==> Caveats
Even without the --with-qt option, you can display native VTK render windows from python. Alternatively, you can integrate the RenderWindowInteractor in PyQt, PySide, Tk or Wx at runtime. Read more:
    import vtk.qt4; help(vtk.qt4) or import vtk.wx; help(vtk.wx)

VTK was linked against your system copy of Python.
If you later decide to change Python installations, relink VTK with:

  brew postinstall vtk
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/vtk/7.0.0_5: 3,204 files, 107.7M
```

And when I `import vtk` on the python console: abortion!

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently updating to vtk/7.0.0_5 (used 7.0.0_3 before), the line I used to install it was :

```
brew install vtk --with-qt --with-qt5 --with-python
```

And I did not get any issue using it in python (2.7).

Ok - So just finished to do the upgrade to 7.0.0_5 and I got the same message tan you. But no issue at all to launch python and launch :

```
> $ python                                                                     
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:20:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
>>> import vtk.qt4
```

Hope that help,

Stephane

Comment: I tried your `brew install vtk --with-qt --with-qt5 --with-python` but it returns `Warning: homebrew/science/vtk-7.0.0_5 already installed`. And the abortion still occurs :/ Could it be a compatibility conflict with another library or something like that ?

Comment: Could you try 
    brew reinstall vtk --with-qt --with-qt5 --with-python 
please ?

Comment: No it didn't work too... The reinstallation change nothing: the importation crashed python...